# Quadratic surfaces: Coordinates and radius( Non origin)

Tags: quadratics, quadratic-forms

So I have a problem figuring out how to find the coordinates and radius to quadratic equations that are not in the form of $$(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2 + (z - z_0)^2 $$

Where the coordinates are going to be: $$(x_0,y_0,z_0)$$

But when I get something like: $$
\left\{\begin{matrix}x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4
\\ x + y + z=1
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

Now the solution manual says this is centered at $$ ( \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}) $$

With the radius at: $$ \sqrt{4- \frac{3}{9}} = \sqrt{\frac{11}{3}} $$

Now I don't see any connection to how one would come to that conclusion with the given information. The book says nothing about it. It say that this is a sphere and a plane that intersect each other.

The next problem is the same idea:
$$ \left\{\begin{matrix}x^2 + y^2 = 1
\\ z = x + y
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
This object is an ellipse intersecting a cylinder, with the coordinates:
$$ +- (1\sqrt{2}, 1\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}) $$
To me this makes no sense at all. I would love for someone to teach me how to get these coordinates and radius with the given parametric information.
Cheers!

Comment: It's not about solving an equation it's about sketching a surface and to find where it's centered.

Answer (score 3):

**Preview**

[image: preview]         
[image: preview]         
[image: preview]         
[image: preview]         
[image: preview]

---

**1.** System of equations
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4
\\ x + y + z=1
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
The first equation is a sphere around the origin $0$ with radius $r = 2$.
The second equation is a plane $E$ through $e_1 = (1,0,0)^T$, $e_2 = (0,1,0)^T$ and $e_3 = (0,0,1)^T$.

[image]

If one combines both equations, one gets the equations of the intersection curve.

We now use the plane equation to express $z$ as function of the $x$ and $y$ coordinates:
$$
z = 1 - x - y \quad (\#)
$$
Putting this into the first equation gives:
\begin{align}
4 &= x^2 + y^2 + (1 - x - y)^2 \\
  &= x^2 + y^2 + 1 + (x + y)^2 - 2(x + y) \\ 
  &= x^2 + y^2 + 1 + x^2 + y^2 + 2xy - 2(x+y) \\
  &= 2(x^2 + y^2 + xy -x -y) + 1
\end{align}
which gives a conic section $A x^2 + B xy + C y^2 + D x + E y + F = 0$:
$$
3/2 = x^2 + y^2 + xy - x - y \quad (*)
$$
The discrimintant $\Delta = B^2 - 4AC = 1 - 4 = -3 < 0$ is negative, so it is an ellipse $C_{xy}$ in the $x$-$y$-plane.

Note: The intersection curve $C$ we get via $(\#)$:
$$
C = \{ (x,y,1-x-y)^T : (x,y)^T \in C_{xy} \}
$$
Back to analyzing $C_{xy}$:

The special case of a circle would require $A = C$ and $B = 0$.  So it is no circle.

Equation $(*)$ can be written as:
$$
u^T A u + b^T u = 1
$$ 
with
$$
A 
=
\frac{2}{3} 
\left[
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
+ 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right)
\right]
=
\frac{2}{3} 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
2/3 & 1/3 \\
1/3 & 2/3
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
and
$$
b = \frac{2}{3}
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-1 \\
-1
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-2/3 \\
-2/3
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
$A$ has the eigenvectors $(1,1)^T$ and $(1, -1)^T$ with the positive eigenvalues $1$ and $1/3$. From this one can infer it is an ellipse as well.

Transforming to normed eigenvectors via $v = P u$ with
$$
P 
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} \\
1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{2} 
\end{matrix}
\right)
\quad
P^{-1} = P = P^T
$$
we get
$$
v^T P A P v + (Pb)^T v = 1
$$
where $PAP = \mbox{diag}(1, 1/3)$ and $(P b)^T = (-\sqrt{8}/3, 0)$. Using $v = (\xi, \eta)^T$ we get
$$
\xi^2 + 1/3 \eta^2 - \sqrt{8}/3 \xi = 1 \iff \\
(\xi - \sqrt{8}/6)^2 + 1/3 \eta^2 = 1 + 8/36 = 1 + 2/9 = 11/9 \iff \\
(\xi - \sqrt{2}/3)^2 + (\eta / \sqrt{3})^2 = (\sqrt{11}/3)^2 \iff \\
\left(\frac{\xi - \sqrt{2}/3}{\sqrt{11}/3}\right)^2 + 
\left(\frac{\eta}{\sqrt{11/3}} \right)^2 = 1 \quad (**)
$$
This is an equation of the form
$$
\left(\frac{x - x_0}{a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y-y_0}{b}\right)^2 = 1
$$
So in the $\xi$-$\eta$-coordinate system, which is mirrored along the $x$-axis and then rotated $-45^\circ$, the projection $C_{xy}$ is an ellipse with origin $v_0 = (\xi_0, \eta_0) = (\sqrt{2}/3, 0)$, 
semi-axis $a = \sqrt{11}/3 \approx 1.11$ in $\xi$-direction, and semi-axis 
$b = \sqrt{11/3}\approx 1.73$ in $\eta$-direction.

[image: C_xy]

Transforming back we have $u_0 = P v_0 = (1/3, 1/3)^T$ as center in the $x$-$y$-plane.
This gives a center $U_0 = (1/3, 1/3, 1-1/3 -1/3)^T = (1/3, 1/3, 1/3)^T$ of $C$.

[image: scene2]

Took a bit to reach the first statement of your instruction manual. :-)

Next bit is determing $C$ from $C_{xy}$.

One way is to parameterize $C_{xy}$ in the $\xi$-$\eta$-system as $v(t)$ then transform back to $u(t) = P v(t)$. Then go into the third dimension via $U(t) = g(u(t))$.
Then go into local coordinates into the plane $w(t) = f(U(t))$.

The expectation is that this is a circle around $w_0 = (0,0)^T$ with radius $\sqrt{11}/3$, the same value as the major semi-axis.

[image: plane view]

**2.** Here we have the system
$$
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
x^2 + y^2 = 1 \\ 
z = x + y
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$

This system is solved by the intersection curve of a cylinder and a plane.

[image: cylinder]

From the above image we suspect it is some ellipse as well.

$$
u 
= (x, y, z)^T  
= (x, \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}, x \pm \sqrt{1 - x^2})^T
= (\cos t, \sin t, \cos t + \sin t)^T  \quad (***)
$$

Looking at the extremal distances from the origin:
$$
0 
= \frac{d}{dt}\lVert u(t) \rVert^2
= \frac{d}{dt} \left((\cos t)^2 + (\sin t)^2 + (\cos t + \sin t)^2\right)
= \frac{d}{dt} 2 (\cos t \sin t)
= 2(-(\sin t)^2 + (\cos t)^2) = 2(2(\cos t)^2 - 1) \iff \\
\cos t = \pm 1/\sqrt{2} \iff t \in \{ \pm \pi/4, \pm 3\pi/4 \}
$$

The minor semi-axis is at 
$u_- = (1/\sqrt{2}, -1/\sqrt{2}, 0)^T$ with 
$\lVert u_- \rVert = 1$ and the major semi-axis at
$u_+ = (1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})^T$ with
$\lVert u_+ \rVert = \sqrt{3}$.

What is left is to ensure that $(***)$ is a parameterized ellipse.
We would need to transform coordinates $u=(x,y,z)^T$ into local coordinates $v = (\xi, \eta, 0)^T$ within the plane.

We use $P (1/\sqrt{2}, -1/\sqrt{2}, 0)^T = (1, 0, 0)^T$ and 
$P(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})^T = (0, \sqrt{3}, 0)^T$.

An orthogonal to the plane is $(1,0,1)^T \times (0,1,1)^T = (-1, -1, 1)^T$ which gives the normal $n = (-1/\sqrt{3}, -1/\sqrt{3}, 1/\sqrt{3})^T$. So we want $P(-1/\sqrt{3},-1/\sqrt{3}, 1/\sqrt{3})^T=(0,0,1)^T$. This gives
$$
P =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{3} \\
-1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{3} \\
0 & \sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{3} \\
\end{matrix}
\right)^{-1}
$$

It turns out that $P u(t)$ describes a parameterized ellipse with semi-axes $1$ and $\sqrt{3}$.

*Note: The images were created with GeoGebra and Gnuplot, some algebra was done and checked with Maxima.*

Comment: I understand that perfectly, but after the $$ 3/2 = x^2 + y^2 + xy - x - y $$ 
Part It don't make any sense to me

Comment: Is there a more intuitive way to solve this?